# Does alien tech scale with time in XCOM: Enemy Unknown?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

If I forgo completing the Alien Base Assault mission for a few game months, will the aliens advance as well, making the mission harder?

I realize incidental missions get more difficult and scale, but does a story mission, like the Alien Base, change the longer I put it off?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it will get harder. I waited a few months on my first play through and was fighting cyberdiscs, cryssalids, and a few mutons.

On my second play through I went right away for the panic reduction and 2-3 cryssalids were the highest level enemy I fought.

Strategically if you can wait and use the assault to reduce panic when you need it, that would be useful.

Comment: These were my observations.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the enemy's tech does not improve BUT their soldiers get harder and harder. Like mutton to berserker to elite mutton.

Comment: I would call plasma pistol -> light plasma rifle -> plasma rifle -> heavy plasma improvements.

Comment: The weapon accompany the alien. The sectoid never will carry a heavy plasma for instance